# Matlab: Can I create a matrix with unknown number of dimensions?

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimension

Normally a matrix has 2 dimensions, but there doesn't seem to be a limit on the number of dimensions a matrix may have in MATLAB.

To create a 4-dimensional matrix, for example, I can do this:

```
>> x = zeros(2,2,2,2)

x(:,:,1,1) =

     0     0
     0     0


x(:,:,2,1) =

     0     0
     0     0


x(:,:,1,2) =

     0     0
     0     0


x(:,:,2,2) =

     0     0
     0     0
```

Is there a way to create a matrix of which the number of dimensions is only known at runtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could call `zeros` like this:

```
x = zeros([2 2 2 2])
```

Hence, you can customize the input array as you want.

For example: to create a 2x2x2x2x2 matrix (where D = 5, the number of dimensions):

```
D = 5;
x = zeros(zeros(1, D) + 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rafael's answer hits the nail on the head. But there's also a general way to do this sort of thing even when the function doesn't have an overload for something like a vector input as in the case of `zeros`. You can use a `cell` array like so:

```
>> dims = {2,2,2,2};
>> zeros(dims{:})
ans(:,:,1,1) =

     0     0
     0     0


ans(:,:,2,1) =

     0     0
     0     0


ans(:,:,1,2) =

     0     0
     0     0


ans(:,:,2,2) =

     0     0
     0     0
```

I've found this approach to be very useful for other functions.

**Edit:**

This approach is more robust. Here's another example:

```
imginfo = { rand(40), [0 1], 'Colormap', colormap(jet) };
figure, imshow(a{:});
```

Comment: I don't understand what the benefit is of this approach over using a vector.

Comment: In matlab, not every function has a vector overload like `zeros`. Using cells is a universal way to call a function with an unknown number of arguments during run time. i.e. the above approach works for every function in Matlab, whereas Rafael's only works for functions that accept a vector as an argument. The only reason I posted this is because I've had to use this approach in code before, so I thought I'd post it for anyone who might be interested.